# Postioning Jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

Basically here is my code :

```
$("#EMIDetails").dialog({
    resizable: false,        
    modal: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    position: 'absolute',
    draggable: true,
    show: {
        effect: "fade",
    },
    buttons: {

    },
    close: function (ev, ui) {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});

this.OpenEMIDetails = function () {

    $("#EMIDetails").dialog("open");

    return false;

}

this.CloseEMIDetails = function () {
    $("#EMIDetails").dialog("close");
    return false;
}
```

### Aspx Code :

```
onclick =""objHandleExpressCheckout.OpenEMIDetails()"" >Know more " & keyValue.Key.ToString & "
```

---

This dialog box is positioned at center. I want it to get it opened at the click of that link and also below that link position.

Any Suggestions??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read [jQuery dialog position option](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)

Change `onclick` to this:

```
onclick =""objHandleExpressCheckout.OpenEMIDetails(this)"" >Know more " & keyValue.Key.ToString & "
```

`this` parameter to get current clicked link.

```
function OpenEMIDetails(obj) {
    $("#EMIDetails").dialog({
        resizable: false,        
        modal: false,
        autoOpen: false,            
        draggable: true,
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
        },
        buttons: {

        },
        close: function (ev, ui) {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: $(obj) }
    });
....
```

`of` can be: Selector or Element or jQuery or Event

Read more about jQuery position: http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: Since The Hyperlink Is Getting Loaded from the .vb file "function OpenEMIDetails(obj)"  obj is Null . .
Any Other solution Please